# running Cassandra from php shell command (using datastax php-driver)

Tags: php, cassandra-2.1, datastax-php-driver

I am able to run it through the browser but not from command line

ie php test.php

```
$raw = Cassandra::cluster()
              ->withContactPoints('localhost')
              //->withCredentials($this->username, $this->password)
              ->build();
 var_dump($raw);                       

die;
```

from browser:

> object(Cassandra\DefaultCluster)#2 (0) { }

command line:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cassandra' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 2

Is it possible to get same from command line as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cli uses a different php.ini file (e.g. `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` & `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini`). You are probably not including the extension in the cli one.